# concatenate a value of a function that requires 2 values

Tags: python

I'm trying to concatenate a value of a function that requires 2 values.
In this scenrio I'm multiplying 2 values together. I attempt to concatenate it normally but instead of printing the values of the 2, it prints it that many times

my code:

```
holiday_cost(hotel_cost(prices[menus[user_hotel+7]],num_nights)
# Hotel_cost is a function within the function of holiday_cost
# Hotel_cost requires the 2 values to multiply
```

i.e. 25x5

output:

```
2525252525
```

my attempt:

```
holiday_cost(hotel(f"£{prices[menus[user_hotel+7]]},{num_nights}))
```

I'm assuming its because of the comma separating the 2 separate concatenated values.
I've tried multiple ways to try find out but couldn't solve it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Please provide example inputs and the output you expect, as well as the output you are getting.

Comment: It sounds like you're multiplying a string value, not a numeric value.  `25*5` is `125`, but `"25"*5` is `"2525252525"`.

Comment: Check out [ask] for more tips, like how to write a good title.

Comment: Your assumption is likely incorrect.   You should have provided the holiday_cost implementation as part of you question.   As @JohnGordon its highly likely that you are passing off a string representation of the cost and not the integer or float value.   you can convert the string to int or float  using functions of the same name (int(), float())

Comment: This resource gives an idea what is going on:  https://www.pythoncentral.io/use-python-multiply-strings/

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a few things can happen when you multiply different data types by a integer:

```
print("25" * 5) # 2525252525
```

and

```
print(25 * 5) # 125
```

In your example, the output matches that of former. That is because the `hotel_cost` function returns a string, instead of an integer that can be multiplied. So, the string is being repeated `num_nights` times.

To fix this, you can use the `int()` function in python.

```
holiday_cost(int(hotel_cost(prices[menus[user_hotel+7]]), num_nights)
```

If this does not answer your question, it is suggested that you provide more details, like an example of how each function computes it's return value (and the return value type).